# Why can I multiply the indicator function with another random variable?

Tags: probability-theory

If we have the indicator function

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{1}_A(\omega) := \begin{cases}1 \text{, if } \omega \in A \\ 0 \text{, if } \omega \notin A\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Also, in comparison, $\mathbf{1}_A$ is just the indicator for the *event* $A$! We also have a random variable $X$. What does

\begin{align*}
X \mathbf{1}_{[X\gt n]} = \ldots
\end{align*}

actually look like? I really don't get my head around this.

---

For example we say

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(X) &= \sum_{x \in E} xp(x)
\end{align*}

I also get that

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{1}_{[X>n]}) &= \sum_{x \in R_{\mathbf{1}_{[X>n]}}} x p_{\mathbf{1}_{[X>n]}}(x)
\end{align*}

where the probability mass function $p_{\mathbf{1}_{[X>n]}}(x)$ is:

\begin{align*}
p_{\mathbf{1}_{[X>n]}}(x) &= \begin{cases}P([X>n]) & \text{if } x = 1 \\
1-P([X>n]) & \text{if } x = 0 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
\end{align*}

But what exactly does this here look like:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(X\mathbf{1}_{[X>n]}) &= ?
\end{align*}

For me this looks like two functions/sets getting "*multiplied*" by each other.

Can somebody clarify this for me?

I'm sure it will be clear once I have the answer but is this actually allowed: $Y \mathbf{1}_{[X>n]}$ for another RV $Y$?

Comment: $$Y \mathbf{1}_{[X>n]}:\Omega\to\mathbb R,\ \omega\mapsto Y(\omega) \mathbf{1}_{[X(\omega)>n]}=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}Y(\omega)&\text{if}&X(\omega)>n\\0&\text{if}&X(\omega)\leqslant n\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: @Did Oh, I think I finally got it .. so I'm actually only looking at


\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(X\mathbf{1}_{[X >n]}) &=\sum_{x \in E} x p(x) \mathbf{1}_{[X(x) >n]}
\end{align*}

is that right?

Comment: If $X$ is discrete, yes, except that the subscript should read $x\in E$ instead of $x\in X$, where $X:\Omega\to E$.

Comment: @Did Alright, thanks! Having a hard time here getting my head around the notation. Thanks for the hint - I corrected the subscript. :)

Comment: @Did It is? I got that from [statlect](https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-probability/indicator-functions) - althouth I see that I made another mistake with the subscript there. ^^

Comment: The modified version is correct, but unnecessarily complicated. Why not simply use $$E(\mathbf 1_{[X>n]})=1\cdot P(X>n)+0\cdot P(X\leqslant n)=P(X>n)\ ?$$

Comment: @Did I think I'm not comfortable enough with the whole notation thing yet - I'm no mathematician so I still have to introduce this to my comfort zone I guess which is why I might over complicate things quite a bit ^^

Comment: @Did Since you didn't provide an answer my thank you is voting some of your answers up which got down voted for no apparent reason ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$X\mathbf{1}_{[X>n]}(\omega)=X(\omega)\mathbf{1}_{[X>n]}(\omega)=\begin{cases}
X\left(\omega\right) & \text{if }X\left(\omega\right)>n\\
0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

If $F$ denotes the CDF of $X$ then

$$\mathbb EX\mathbf{1}_{[X>n]}=\int x\mathbf{1}_{[x>n]}dF(x)=\int_{(n,\infty)}xdF(x)$$

If there is a PDF $f$ then:$$\mathbb EX\mathbf{1}_{[X>n]}=\int_{(n,\infty)}xf(x)dx$$

If there is a PMF $p$ on a countable support $E$ then:$$\mathbb EX\mathbf{1}_{[X>n]}=\sum_{x\in E\wedge x>n}xp(x)$$

Evidently we also have: $$\mathbb E\mathbf{1}_{[X>n]}=\Pr(X>n)$$

Comment: I think I understand this now but imho the last line is tricky. It hides the fact that one actually sums over all values where $x \leq n$ if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: While you were writing your comment I was busy with perfectioning.

Comment: :D Just saw it - maybe it's just me but the notation @Did used was a little bit clearer for me. I understand that you can show this but what I was missing I guess was this explicit use of $\mathbf{1}_{[X >n]}$ as a factor inside the sum to finally open my eyes. But still thanks for the explanation!

Comment: You are welcome.